# refactor PHP legacy code to REST API

Tags: php, refactoring, legacy

I have a big PHP legacy codebase and I was planning to move it to a MVC based pattern. Not because I want, but if I could separate the views, It would be easier to give the views/layouts with a mockup backend to designers.

Our application is really complicated to setup locally (we are working to make it easier, but its not easy, because it runs on a specific OS, read-only FS, etc).

So my first idea was: Move the whole view logic to templates and then with the time migrate the rest of the code to models and controllers. However now, I'm considering to pack my code in a REST API (no view logic on the server side, just JSON being delivered. View I want to render with backbone.js).

Questions that I still don't have answers are:

- Anyone has an experience similar to share with me?
- PHP rest API lib that I should use? (I'm thinking about SLIM Framework)
- Is it a good approach?

Comment: can you share your thoughts? May be as an answer.